# Likelihood of true lambda decreases as I use more samples of a Poisson R.V

Tags: maximum-likelihood, poisson-distribution, likelihood

Can anyone prove the fact that for samples of a Poisson distribution, the log-likelihood of true (real) lambda is decreased as the number of samples is increased? Or even is it true?
I have calculated the log of the likelihood for ground truth lambda = 20, with some generated data with `np.random.poisson(lam = 20, size = n)`.
As I increase `n` the log-likelihood is decreased.
I wondered why this is happening, so I tried to write log-likelihood, to set `n` to infinity and justify my observation, mathematically:
[image: log-likelihood of poission]

Comment: Hi geradism, there are blind and visually impaired users of this site
who interact with it using screen readers. The screen readers 
can't handle the equation in your screenshot. Please edit the 
post to include the equation as LaTeX. If it helps, we have some 
[resources on using LaTeX on Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1605/155836).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected and completely fine.

Your log-likelihood of the model is the sum of the log-probabilities of each observation, given that parameter. (This is because we assume the data are i.i.d.)

$$\log L(\lambda \mid \vec{x}) = \sum_i \log P(x_i \mid \lambda)$$

These summands are all negative. As you add more terms (from more data points), this sum becomes more negative.

This is true, regardless of whether your model $\lambda$ is the true value.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem if the log likelihood goes to negative infinity. This can happen to several statistical models. Consider the following example.

Let $\mathbf{X} = (X_i)_{i=1}^n$ be i.i.d. observations from the one dimensional exponential with density

$$f_{\theta^*}(x) = h(x)e^{-\theta^*T(x) - \psi(\theta)} \quad.$$

Your log likelihood function for the i.i.d. sample then

$$ l(\theta; \mathbf{X}) = \left[\sum_{i=1}^n log(h(x_i))\right] - \theta\left[\sum_{i=1}^n T(x_i)\right] - n\psi(\theta)\quad.$$

Suppose that $H = E[log(h(X_1))]$ exists. Denote by $\bar{H} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nlog(h(x_i))$ and $\bar{T} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n T(x_i)$. We have

$$\frac{1}{n} l(\theta; \mathbf{X}) = \bar{H} - \theta\bar{T} - \psi(\theta) \quad.$$

It is possible to prove that $E[T(X_1)] = \psi'(\theta^*)$. By the Strong Law of Large Numbers and Continuous Mapping theorem, it follows that

$$\frac{1}{n} l(\theta; \mathbf{X}) \overset{a.s.}{\longrightarrow} H - \theta\psi'(\theta^*) - \psi(\theta) \quad.$$

If RHS is negative evaluated at $\theta^*$, then $l(\theta; \mathbf{X})$ will diverge to $-\infty$ almost surely for any $\theta$.

As an exercise, you might want to check that these holds for the Poisson distribution.

This might be confusing since the log likelihood is decreasing even for the true parameter. A better perspective is given by the following question: what happens to the log likelihood difference as the sample sizes grow. That is, given the true parameter $\theta^*$ and $\theta \neq \theta^*$, what happens to

$$l(\theta^*;\mathbf{X}) - l(\theta;\mathbf{X}) \quad$$

as $n$ goes to infinite? For well behaved families

$$l(\theta^*;\mathbf{X}) - l(\theta;\mathbf{X}) \overset{a.s.}{\longrightarrow} +\infty \quad,$$

which is what you would expect.